# How to do jquery loop for click function

Tags: jquery

Is there a simple way to make a quiz (several questions with multiple choice + picture) using click button function?

I am trying to do it but it moves only to the next (second) question and then it stops.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#button").click(function(){
        $("#question_form.show").toggleClass("show");
        $("#question_form").next().addClass("show");
    });
});
```

---

```
<form id="question_form" class="show">
    <img src="image1.png" id="current_image" alt="">
     <h3 id="question"> Question 1: </h3> 
    <hr>
    <input type="radio" name="q1" value="q1-a">Answer 1
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="q1" value="q1-b">Answer 2
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="q1" value="q1-c">Answer 3
    <br>
    <br>
    <input name="button" type="button" id="button" value="Next">
</form>
<form id="question_form" class="">
    <img src="image2.png" id="current_image" alt="">
     <h3 id="question"> Question 2: </h3> 
    <hr>
    <input type="radio" name="q2" value="q2-a">Answer 1
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="q2" value="q2-b">Answer 2
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="q2" value="q2-c">Answer 3
    <br>
    <br>
    <input name="button" type="button" id="button" value="Next">
</form>
<form id="question_form" class="">
    <img src="image.png" id="current_image" alt="">
     <h3 id="question"> Question 3: </h3> 
    <hr>
    <input type="radio" name="q3" value="q3-a">Answer 1
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="q3" value="q3-b">Answer 2
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="q3" value="q3-c">Answer 3
    <br>
    <br>
    <input name="button" type="button" id="button" value="Next">
</form>
```

---

```
.show {
    display: inline; 
}
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: IDs **must** be unique.

Comment: Why `toggleClass()`? You could `removeClass()` instead.

Comment: @j08691 is correct. You must use `class` if you want them to be the same.

Comment: @CaolanEvans I think the OP meant `toggleClass('show hide')` to avoid calling `addClass` followed by `removeClass`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting @j08291's comment into an answer.

You can only have one element with an ID. Change them to classes, and you'll need to do some tree traversing to get the reference to the correct  form elements to show and hide http://jsfiddle.net/pcUBr/

Also, your CSS class names (`show,hide`) aren't very semantic. Try the following

**CSS**

```
.question_form {
    display: none;
}
.question_form.current {
   display: inline;    
}
```

**JS**

```
$(".button").click(function(e){
    var form = $(e.target).closest('form');
    form.toggleClass("current");
    form.next().toggleClass("current");
});
```

**HTML**

```
<form class="question_form current" >
    <img src="image1.png" class="current_image" alt="">
     <h3 class="question"> Question 1: </h3> 
    <hr>
    <input type="radio" name="q1" value="q1-a">Answer 1
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="q1" value="q1-b">Answer 2
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="q1" value="q1-c">Answer 3
    <br>
    <br>
    <input name="button" type="button" class="button" value="Next">
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for the nice example!

Comment: I do not know why, but it's not working when I pasted it into  Notepad++. When you click on the button nothing is happened.

Comment: @user3621871 You can clearly see from my jsfiddle  that it does work. You must have copied something wrong...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using the same ID for your components, the form's, the img's and the button's.
The IDs must be unique (like @j08691 sad)

Try modifying the attribute to "class", then modify in your script from "#" to ".", like this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".button").click(function(event){
        var form = $(event.target).closest('form'); // or you can use $(event.target).parent(); for your HTML
        $(".question_form.show").toggleClass("show hide");
        form.next().toogleClass("show hide");
    });
});
```

Your HTML code must be like this:

```
<form class="question_form show">
    <img src="image1.png" class="current_image" alt="">
     <h3 class="question"> Question 1: </h3> 
    <hr>
    <input type="radio" name="q1" value="q1-a">Answer 1
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="q1" value="q1-b">Answer 2
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="q1" value="q1-c">Answer 3
    <br>
    <br>
    <input name="button" type="button" class="button" value="Next">
</form>
<form class="question_form hide">
    <img src="image2.png" class="current_image" alt="">
     <h3 class="question"> Question 2: </h3> 
    <hr>
    <input type="radio" name="q2" value="q2-a">Answer 1
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="q2" value="q2-b">Answer 2
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="q2" value="q2-c">Answer 3
    <br>
    <br>
    <input name="button" type="button" class="button" value="Next">
</form>
<form class="question_form hide">
    <img src="image.png" class="current_image" alt="">
     <h3 class="question"> Question 3: </h3> 
    <hr>
    <input type="radio" name="q3" value="q3-a">Answer 1
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="q3" value="q3-b">Answer 2
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="q3" value="q3-c">Answer 3
    <br>
    <br>
    <input name="button" type="button" class="button" value="Next">
</form>
```

Comment: You're not correctly getting the form element that corresponds to the form for the button that was clicked, you have to traverse the tree. See my answer

Comment: You should be toggling both `.show`  and `.hide` classes.